# Why the `.tex` file is running indefinitely in PdfLaTeX?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am using the following code to plot a set of graphs from the experimental data given in `book1.txt`. This `.txt` file is also kept in the same folder along with `.tex`. My `book1.txt` file is

```
A       B   C   D   E   F
0.05    5   9   19  7   10
0.10    8   9   19  9   10
0.15    11  9   19  10  10
0.20    12  9   19  10  19
0.25    14  9   19  11  19
0.30    15  9   19  11  11
0.35    15  9   19  11  11
0.40    16  9   19  11  19
0.45    17  9   19  11  12
0.50    17  9   19  11  12
```

and my `.tex` file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{book1.txt}\datatable
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={Equilibrium thresholds dependence on setup time},
    xlabel={$\theta$},
    ylabel={Equilibrium thresholds},
    xmin=0, xmax=0.5,
    ymin=0, ymax=20,
%   xtick={0,.1,.2,.3,.40,.5,.60,.7,.80},
%   ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25},
    legend style={at={(axis cs:0.3,0.5)},anchor=south west},
    %legend entries={B,C,D,E,F}]
    \addplot[color = black, mark  = *] table[y = B] from \datatable ;
    \addlegendentry{\textbf{B}}
    \addplot[color = black, mark= halfcircle] table[y = C] from \datatable ;
    \addplot table[y = D] from \datatable ;
    \addplot table[y = E] from \datatable ;
    \addplot table[y = F] from \datatable ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code is running indefinitely in `PdfLaTeX`. Where is the error in my code?

Comment: The closing `]` in the `axis` options, at the end of the `legend entries` line, is commented out, move it to the next line.

Comment: Usually when your code keeps going (check your task manager for zombie processes by the way), you have unbalanced brackets, as @Torbjørn T. pointed out, or you're missing a `;` somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In commenting out the `legend entries` key you have also commented out the closing bracket for the axis options. Moving the bracket at the end of that line to the next line should solve this.